# Managing indexes in MultiIndex Dataframe to turn them into dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, multi-index

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
                     brand  price
event_time      
2019-10-01 00:02:14 samsung 130.76
2019-10-01 00:04:37 apple   642.69
2019-10-01 00:06:02 xiaomi  29.51
2019-10-01 00:07:07 santeri 54.42
2019-10-01 00:09:26 apple   189.91
... ... ...
2019-11-30 23:58:14 samsung 346.70
2019-11-30 23:58:22 apple   1437.02
2019-11-30 23:58:57 samsung 235.60
2019-11-30 23:59:15 polaris 89.32
```

And I need to calculate the mean price for each brand and for each month, so I did this:

```
sub_df = sub_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'brand'])['price'].mean()
```

Which outputs this:

```
event_time  brand          price
2019-10-31  a-case       4.745862
            a-derma     12.360000
            a-mega     114.607778
            abk         11.560000
            abtoys      46.310000
                          ...    
2019-11-30  zotac      272.305714
            zte         79.501161
            zubr        89.318436
            zuru        12.840000
            zvezda      11.970000
```

And in order to explore the data more easily, I wanted to transform the whole thing into a dictionary. The problem is that the dictionary will have a double key, instead of having like multiple levels! What I did was writing this:

```
dic_returns = sub_df.groupby(level='event_time').apply(lambda sub_df: 
                                         sub_df.xs(sub_df.name).to_dict()).to_dict()
```

and when I call the dictionary it gives:

```
{(Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'a-case'): 4.745862068965517,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'a-derma'): 12.36,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'a-mega'): 114.60777777777781,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'abk'): 11.56,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'abtoys'): 46.31,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'acer'): 519.720941586739,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'achilles'): 66.06214285714287,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'acm'): 25.69666666666667,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'acme'): 48.95154761904759,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'acqua'): 2.96,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'acron'): 15.42,
 (Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'), 'activision'): 45.31161290322581
```

Instead, what I would love to have is something like:

```
{2019-10-31: {'a-case': 4.745862068965517, 'a-derma': 12.36, 'a-mega': 114.60777777777781},
2019-11-30:  {'a-case': 272.305714, 'a-derma': 79.501161, 'a-mega': 11.970000}}
```

Is it possible?? Cause the thing is also that since I only have one column, python has transformed my DataFrameGroupBy object into a Series, so I can't use .get_group()!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
pd.DataFrame(sub_df.groupby(by=["event_time", "brand"])["price"].mean()).reset_index().set_index("event_time").T.to_dict()
```

This is how it looked on my test data:
[image]